# How can I list all the IPs on which youtube and netflix operate (effectively getting all DNS A and AAAA records)?

Tags: dns, youtube, ip, cdn

Youtube and Netflix operate on Content Distributed Networks probably. I realized that Youtube operates on Google and Netflix on Amazon Web services. So, I can't exactly get the IPs on which they operate. Youtube is under AS Number 15169 i.e belongs to google and Netflix responds using several ASNs belonging to AWS like 15609 and 14168.

So, IP ASN lookups like

`'curl https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup/?q=AS15169'`

will provide wrong answers I think as they list all IPs of google also.

`dig youtube.com`

provides

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> youtube.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36383
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;youtube.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
youtube.com.        300 IN  A   172.217.161.142

;; Query time: 599 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue May 19 04:21:33 IST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

which is same as the one obtained by pinging youtube but the address changes if we change our location using VPNs

`dig netflix.com`

provides

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13053
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;netflix.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   54.71.93.100
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   54.149.160.164
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   35.166.180.66
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   35.165.194.49
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   52.41.168.84
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   34.208.21.204
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   54.68.234.134
netflix.com.        60  IN  A   52.34.38.200

;; Query time: 581 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Tue May 19 04:21:14 IST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 168
```

It also changes with VPNs.

It will be great if I can obtain confirmed IPs used by Youtube and Netflix.

Comment: In case of google.com and youtube.com, it seems like it is using concepts of virtual hosting. At least thats what I observed from telnet client ! Take any IP and set the ``HOST`` header field to www.google.com and send request, try the same by setting ``HOST`` field to www.youtube.com. In both the cases, you will get a valid HTTP response but in first case you will get response under the name of ``gws`` server and in the second case you will get response under the name of ``Youtube Frontend Proxy`` server. I can post screenshots if you want :)

Comment: " 'curl https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup/?q=AS15169'

will provide wrong answers I think as they list all IPs of google also. " -- If all servers in AS15169 are used for delivering content then the list you get is correct. But by no means you can take it for granted. The apt way is to get all the ``A`` and ``AAAA`` DNS records that points to name youtube.com

Comment: yeah but this API provides all the IPs which are not only youtube's but also google's So this gives a huge set of IPs which includes 8.8.8.8 the googles host IP.  so I think it will provide all google servers also which are not associated with youtube.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my answer clearly... The servers that receive requests for youtube and google are same... but definitely in the interior different servers are going to work on request. It is able to do that using virtual hosting. Any server that is able to serve google.com servers youtube.com aslo (thats my initial thought) you can check it by considering few random google.com ips. 8.8.8.8 is not google host ip ! Its Google's public DNS server